# Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException can't deliver broadcast

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, broadcastreceiver, localbroadcastmanager

I am receiving

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException
can't deliver broadcast
```

in my app. I have broadcast receiver set in my activity. It is registered as

```
val filter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
val receiver = MyReceiver()
context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
```

here context refers to my activity context. When I searched for this exception, I saw posts saying that we should use

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
```

When I changed the code to this statement, it doesn't enter my `onReceive()`. What is the right way to implement the same so that I can avoid this exception.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are seeing this in Sentry, Crashlytics, or some similar crash-reporting service, most likely you are seeing [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245258072). Reportedly it has been fixed, though we still see some devices that have not received the patch with the fix.

Comment: Yes, I saw this exception in crashlytics. In my case, this exception has occurred on Samsung devices with the Android 12 version.

Comment: @Anju: That's where I see it too. Fortunately, the frequency has been decreasing, though it is unlikely to ever reach zero.

Comment: Is there any chance of increasing the crash count if we integrate the firebase remote config? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Anju: I do not see how Firebase Remote Config would impact the frequency of this crash.

Comment: For the last update, this crash had gone up and we had this Firebase remote config feature newly added too. @CommonsWare